# Import ZFS Pool from FreeNAS (not supported com.delphix:embedded_data)

Tags: 14.04, zfs

I am trying to import a pool that I exported from FreeNAS. I originally installed `zfs-fuse` however it was not a new enough version. I removed that and installed `ubuntu-zfs` from the PPA. Here is an error message I get now:

```
sudo zpool import

pool: Storage1
id: <omitted>
state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool uses the following feature(s) not supported on this system:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

Unfortunately I do not have enough extra storage space to copy this data out and recreate the pool. Is there anything I can do in place to mount this pool in Ubuntu?

I found [these](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/hole_birth-zfs-feature-freenas-orphan.18966/) [posts](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/import-freenas-9-3-zfs-volume-into-ubuntu-14-04.26246/), but I am hoping there is something newer that I just couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

Update: [0.6.4 was tagged yesterday](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/commit/d07a16360c1ee219b8820f80d035e56a18c58b84) and I just received a notification that updated packages are available in the PPA.

---

I found [this comment from the owner](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2782#issuecomment-68952100) of the GitHub ZoL repository:

> Those features (and more) have been added to the master branch and will be part of 0.6.4. The intention was to update the OpenZFS docs once that release is tagged. You must have run `zpool upgrade` while running the master branch and enabled them. My suggestion would be to run the zfs-testing repository which supports this features until the stable tag is released.

So far I have been unable to find a zfs-testing repository for Ubuntu on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezfs-native). If you don't want to checkout and compile the code yourself, then running CentOS with EPEL might be a solution:

> In addition to the primary **zfs** repository a **zfs-testing** repository is available. This repository, which is disabled by default, contains the latest versions of zfs which are under active development. These packages are made available in order to get feedback from testers regarding the functionality and stability of upcoming releases. These packages **should not** be used on production systems. Packages from the testing repository can be installed as follows.
>
> ```
> $ sudo yum --enablerepo=zfs-testing install kernel-devel zfs
> ```